# Light bars for off-road vehicle

Tags: nissan, terrain

Im thinking of adding some lights (specifically a light bar of some sort)to my off-road 4x4 vehicle. I don't want to connect it to my battery or electrics as this will void my electrics' warranty on the car.

I've recently found some light bars that work using solar; do you reckon solar would be enough to charge such energy intensive LEDs, or the energy produced would be too low? I live in Dubai btw which is sunny all year round :p

I've found a few that work on solar on Alibaba which can be shipped from China, which is partly why I'm reluctant to go for them.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Connecting aftermarket lighting to your system should not void your warranty, as long as it is installed correctly. People do this all the time without issue or trouble.

Comment: And getting anything along this line from Alibaba sounds like a prescription for disaster.

Comment: Cheers mate; yeah Alibaba is kind of putting me off from getting them. Will prolly look for others out there in the market.

Comment: Not necessarily guaranteed disaster @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, more like the roll of a dice. It may work amazingly well or break before it's even used.

Comment: @GdD - Definitely hit or miss. Considering what the OP is searching for, solar powered anything is not something I'd be looking towards Alibaba to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to comment about the lights you have seen, since you have not shared them with us.

The answer is yes, it is possible to use solar power to charge the batteries in the lights.

After saying that however, it depends on the capacity of the batteries, the output of the solar panels and the current requirements of the LEDs.

You may find that a full day of sun only charges the batteries to operate the LEDs for 30 minutes for example. It may be even worse than this. With most things you get what you pay for.  You really need to compare specifications.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply; I will go over the specs again and contact the supplier for the same.